# Disable DVD autorun on double-click

Tags: windows-7, windows, autorun

I use Windows 7 x64. I thought I disabled Autorun - that is nothing happens when DVD/CD is inserted. However, by accident I found out that if in Windows Explorer I go to "My Computer" and then double-click on DVD icon in the right pan Autorun still works. Is there a way to disable this as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are running into isn't AutoRun, or AutoPlay.  It's the 'default action' for double clicking on a DVD, which is "Play".  If you right-click the drive (with a DVD in it), you'll see "Play" is highlighted.

If you would prefer it to "Open" the DVD as a folder instead of playing the movie when you double-click the drive, then you could try editing the registry and change the action for the "DVD" class:

- Open `regedit.exe`.
- Navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DVD\shell`
- Change the "Default" value data from "Play" to "Open" (without quotes).

I believe the change should take effect immediately, but I'm not 100% sure, as I don't have a DVD disc around to test with right now. :)

Comment: Yep, that did it. Took effect immediately, no reboot needed.