# Change default action for DVD drive

Tags: windows-10, file-association, autorun

In File Explorer, when I right-click my DVD drive, "Install or run program from your media" is highlighted. When I double-click my DVD drive, it runs the executable specified in AUTORUN.INF. How do I change the default action to "Open" so that when I double-click my DVD drive, it just opens it in File Explorer to show me the contents?

I attempted the [solution for Windows 7](https://superuser.com/a/331699/530338), but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

- Press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> and type `autoplay`.
- Select `AutoPlay`

[image: AutoPlay Options]

- Set the AuytoPlay options item-by-item, **or**
- Uncheck `Use AutoPlay for all media and devices` to allow you to prevent automatic (possibly risky) actions.