# File Explorer CD/DVD default action: disable "install or run program from your media"

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, compact-disc, installer, double-click

When inserting a CD/DVD medium, I already disabled autoplay from within Settings / Devices / Autoplay first and, then, from within Control Panel / Autoplay which is more complete. However, even with that, explorer.exe file explorer windows keep "install or run program from your media" as default *manual* action. Please, see below the screen capture:

[image]

I'd like to disable any double-click leading to something different than opening the medium in the file explorer as when I open any fixed drive root directory.

Any ideas?

Note: I'm not making allusions here to the USB thumbdrives driver autoinstall, a perfectly valid subject, but not the subject here. I just want to prevent myself from accidentally running some software from a CV/DVD by manual double-clicking only wanting to explore the contents (having already covered autorun beforehand).

Note 2: I stand by the fact that my question might be a duplicate of [Change default action for DVD drive](https://superuser.com/questions/1322222/change-default-action-for-dvd-drive), but at the time I wrote mine, the only answer was off the mark referring to autoplay, where this wasn't the question from the original user and mine neither. So, to be clear, this is not about autoplay, but about default *manual* action. My autoplay is already set beforehand to "Take no action" everywhere and, *still*, this "install" stuff default action is there. See below:

[image]